# SQL Natural Join 2 matching columns

Tags: sql, database, join

What if 2 columns have the same name in a natural join of 2 tables?
Which tuples will be selected, is it enough if one column value is the same or does it require both columns then

Comment: A natural join will use all columns with the same name.  You should use a `using` or `on` clause instead, because these don't depend on the underlying table structure.

Comment: i understand that but will it only accept rows that match all common columns or is 1 match enough even if 2 column-names match

Comment: All columns with matching names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Table1 NATURAL JOIN Table2
```

is equivalent to

```
 Table1 JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
 AND Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2
 ...
```

with all column names which exist in both tables being added to the ON clause.

So yes, since it is an AND not an OR which is implied, they must all match.

This is useful if you have a 2-part Key, e.g. `company_code` + `username`, and a hazard if you have standard named non-key fields, such as `date_created`.